# Set ListBox Selected Values on HTML Table ASP.Net MVC

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, listbox

I have a problem setting the selected values of a **ListBox** in a **HTML Table**. Retrieving the selected values is not a problem but instead setting its values on page load.

**HTML:**

```
@model MVCSample.Models.SampleViewModel

<h2>Index</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
            <hr />
            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Select</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Details.Count(); i++)
                    {
                        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Details[i].Name)

                        <tr>
                            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Details[i].Name)</td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.Details[i].Selected, Model.List, new { @class = "form-control", multiple = "multiple" })
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}
```

**Model:**

```
namespace MVCSample.Models
{
    public class SampleViewModel
    {
        public SelectList List { get; set; }
        public List<SampleDetailsViewModel> Details { get; set; }
    }

    public class SampleDetailsViewModel
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string[] Selected { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
namespace MVCSample.Controllers
{
public class SampleController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        SampleViewModel model = new SampleViewModel();
        model.List = new SelectList(new[] { "1", "2", "3" });

        model.Details = new List<SampleDetailsViewModel>() { 
            new SampleDetailsViewModel {
                Name="Sample1", 
                Selected= new[]{"1"}
            }
        };

        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(SampleViewModel model)
    {
        model.List = new SelectList(new[] { "1", "2", "3" });
        return View(model);
    }

}
}
```

AS you can see, upon declaring the values for **model.Details** I set the selected value to **1**.

But on the picture below, no value was selected after page load.

[image]

**OBJECTIVE: To be able to set the selected values of ListBox on HTML Table on page load.**

**SUGGESTED SOLUTION:**

**VIEW:**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
            <hr />
            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Select</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Details.Count(); i++)
                    {
                        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Details[i].Name)

                        <tr>
                            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Details[i].Name)</td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Details[i].Selected, new SelectList(Model.List, "ID", "Name", Model.Details[i].Selected), new { @class = "form-control", multiple = "multiple" })
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}
```

**MODEL:**

```
namespace MVCSample.Models
{
public class SampleViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<OptionViewModel> List { get; set; }
    public List<SampleDetailsViewModel> Details { get; set; }
}

public class OptionViewModel
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class SampleDetailsViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public OptionViewModel Selected { get; set; }
}
```

}

**CONTROLLER:**

```
public class SampleController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        SampleViewModel model = new SampleViewModel();
        model.List = new OptionViewModel[] { new OptionViewModel() { ID = "1", Name = "1" }, new OptionViewModel() { ID = "2", Name = "2" } };

        model.Details = new List<SampleDetailsViewModel>() { 
            new SampleDetailsViewModel {
                Name="Sample1", 
                Selected = new OptionViewModel() { ID = "1", Name = "1" }
            }
        };

        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(SampleViewModel model)
    {
        model.List = new OptionViewModel[] { new OptionViewModel() { ID = "1", Name = "1" }, new OptionViewModel() { ID = "2", Name = "2" } };
        return View(model);
    }

}
```

Comment: Unfortunately `ListBoxFor()` and `DropDownListFor()` don't work correctly inside a `for` loop - refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30909070/html-dropdownlistfor-default-selected-value-in-mvc5/30911222#30911222)

Comment: Is there any other option?

Comment: Not that I am aware of. I believe its going to be fixed in the next release of MVC (vNext) but not sure.

Comment: I tried the Option 2 on the link that you gave but its not also working

Comment: You will need to show the code you tried - I can't guess what you did :)

Comment: Updated sir. Please check if its correct :)

Comment: I'm hungry too...lunch time here in 30 mins @_@

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately ListBoxFor() and DropDownListFor() don't work correctly inside a for loop. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30909070/html-dropdownlistfor-default-selected-value-in-mvc5/30911222#30911222) gives 2 possible solutions - using a custom `EditorTemplate` for typeof `SampleDetailsViewModel` and passing the `SelectList` as additionalViewData to the template, or creating a new `MultiSelectList` in each iteration of the loop.

Based on your edit, you have tried the 2nd option, however your code contains a few errors.

A `<select mutiple="multiple" ..>` can only bind to an array of value types (not a complex object (in your case `OptionViewModel`). Change the view model to

```
public class SampleDetailsViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    // public OptionViewModel Selected { get; set; }
    public string[] Selected { get; set; } // change this
}
```

and in the controller when you initialize your view model

```
model.Details = new List<SampleDetailsViewModel>()
{ 
    new SampleDetailsViewModel
    {
        Name="Sample1",  
        // Selected = new OptionViewModel() { ID = "1", Name = "1" },
        Selected = new string[] { "1" } // change this
    }
};
```

and finally in the view, it needs to be `MultiSelectList` (not `SelectList`)

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Details[i].Selected,
    new MultiSelectList(Model.List, "ID", "Name", Model.Details[i].Selected),
    new { @class = "form-control", multiple = "multiple" }
)
```

Comment: Sir, should I edit the above post if I got the correct solution? Noob question

Comment: No. If you did my answer wouldn't make any sense.

Comment: Ok sir...I just thinking for the complete solution :)

Comment: Hi Sir, I encountered another issue after HttpPost

Comment: Are you expecting me to guess what it is? :)

Comment: Hi Sir, please see the my answer below for the other issue :)

Comment: Updated the post above. Sorry Senpai :c